# Parse XML and HTML in apache pig

Tags: html, xml, parsing, apache-pig

How can we run the XML using apache pig. I tried with the piggybank.storage.XMLLoader function but its not working for me. Am running the pig job in local mode only. There is no errors but its not running.

Is there a way to parse the HTML pages in the apache pig.

Please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Parsing HTML with a XML interpreter, generally speaking, does not work anyway. Only very, very, very, very few HTML documents are well formed XML. Even most HTML5 isn't. These are different specifications/format.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader() with arguments.
and Xpath as well. i found [this](http://bigdataprogrammers.com/load-xml-file-pig/) one helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the script in MR mode. Because many of the functions / operations work fine only in MR mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
register <PIG_HOME>/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar; 
A= LOAD '/xmlfile' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('<XML_tag>');
```

And by pig MR mode I meant running pig in MR mode and not in local mode (i.e. pig -x local).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks gargi, you are right. Am not running the pig script in local mode. I've 4 node cluster(3+1) for my testing. the same code only i tried. Its working but how can we get attributes and nested nodes in the given XML File.

Comment: As per my knowledge, we will have to go for Custom parser in this case.